# How do I remove all the elements of an array using splice

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an algorithm challenge on freecodecamp and I think is part of the process. If I details are needed I'll be happy to oblige.

Comment: `arr.splice;arr.length=0;`

Comment: `arr = []` would probably be more efficient (unless you actually need to mutate the array)

Comment: emptying an array is very different from getting another one

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't realize that this question was already answered.